# Fixed top navbar is causing an issue while jumping to an ID with href attribute of <a> element

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar which has following css `position: fixed;` `top: 0;` in my html. And i want to jump to selected ID with href attribute of `<a>` elements in navbar by clicking. But if you try to click them you will realize that you wont be able to jump to beginning of that element because of the height of navbar.

How do i prevent this without changing position and top properties of navbar and without changing any padding or margin value? Also I will make html responsive so probably all element's height and width will change.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        nav {
            background-color: black;
            height: 90px;
            color: #f0f0f0;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        section {
            height: 1000px;
        }

        #test1 {
            margin-top: 90px;
            background-color: lightslategray;
        }

        #test2 {
            background-color: lightgray;
        }

        #test3 {
            background-color: lightslategray;
        }

        #test4 {
            background-color: lightgray;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <nav>
        <h1>This is navbar</h1>
        <a href="#test1">TEST1</a>
        <a href="#test2">TEST2</a>
        <a href="#test3">TEST3</a>
        <a href="#test4">TEST4</a>
    </nav>

    <section id="test1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis, illum!</section>
    <section id="test2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis, illum!</section>
    <section id="test3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis, illum!</section>
    <section id="test4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis, illum!</section>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```css
html{
   scroll-padding-top: 90px;
}
```